# Thin grey lines at top and bottom of ios app

Tags: cordova

I'm trying to make a cordova app with a completely black background. I've got pretty much all the way, but I just can't figure out what is causing 2 thin grey bars top and bottom of the screen. After the LaunchImage is displayed, I see a brief plain grey background, and then the webview is overlaid. But it is 4 pixels 'shorter' (2 at the top, and 2 at the bottom). I can't figure out where this is coming from.

I've added the `cordova-plugin-webviewcolor` plugin, and set that to black. I can see that's working because on rotation, and on overscroll, the 'revealed' backround is indeed black (or any other colour I set with that plugin). But I still see the 2 grey lines between my app and the 'background'.

Here's a screenshot - I've overlaid the actual screenshot onto a slightly larger red canvas, so you can see the grey more easily. On the phone, there's no red border, just the thin lines top and bottom of the screen. Any pointers as to where this comes from, and if it's possible to remove?

[image]

Comment: Can you just use web inspector of Safari for css details?

Comment: Not sure I follow. This is a native ios app built via cordova. On the web build, it looks absolutely fine...

Comment: You can still perform run-time debugging using Safari's built-in developer console. http://geeklearning.io/apache-cordova-and-remote-debugging-on-ios/

Comment: Many thanks @filipvkovic! My first go at using cordova for this, and I didn't know the full set of tools. Based on your pointer, I've found the problem, and answered the actual question below.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @filipvkovic for the pointers on debugging. This turned out to be an empty 'header' and 'footer' div that the web framework (VueJS and Quasar) I'm using inserted. They are invisible on desktop browsers, but show up for some reason when baked into an app. So, recoded the layout to avoid them, and all is good.